Error: object 'fread' not found
Buen día;
Después de un largo tiempo de no utilizar R, el día de hoy intenté correr la siguiente línea:
BasePeS <- lapply(paste0(LigaPes,"/",ArchivosPeS),fread,sep = ";", dec = ".", header = FALSE) 

Pero me arroja lo siguiente
Error: object 'fread' not found


fread no es una función estándar, por lo que o cargas antes library(data.table) o bien referencias a la función como data.table::fread

Debes instalar el paquete data.table , ya que este es el que contiene la función llamada fread, después cargas el paquete data.table:
> install.packages("data.table")
> library(data.table)

Revisa el artículo:
Importación de datos usando data.table – fread en R

Hola Jorge, gracias por tú respusta, ya instale el paquete con exito pero al llamar la library (data.table) me sigue arrojando el error Error in library(data.table) : no hay paquete llamado ‘data.table’

ok! instala de esta forma: install.packages("data.table", dependencies=TRUE)
